# Efficient iteration means in SQL server, to retrieve data after certain operation on each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've a simple table i.e.

- ID int,
- value varchar(100)

value column consists of delimited strings e.g.

---

### - ID  -  Value

- 1   -  a,b,c,d
- 2   -  b,e
- 3   -  c
- 4   -  r

---

I need to retrieve all the values from this after splitting each value based on the delimiter i.e. '.'

I've a user defined function to split the string. 
What could be the correct/efficient way to do it? i am looking to avoid iterating over each row, and then splitting the string.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @RedDevil a b c d e r   -  each distinct val from delimited string after splitting the value

Comment: What have you tried till now? Please go through[minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post an attempt.

Comment: The correct and efficient way to solve this problem is to normalize your wrong database structure - and stop storing delimited strings as column values. For more information, read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Comment: Which sql version u r using?

Comment: @Ljt  sql verision is SQL 2012

Comment: @ZoharPeled Agree, that could be done, but some how if this mess is there so just looking how this could come across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cross apply you can retrieve all the Rows. (Assuming dbo.Split_fun is your split function & value is return column name)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #CityList
GO

CREATE TABLE #CityList
(Country VARCHAR(100),
City VARCHAR(5000))
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #contacts;
CREATE TABLE #contacts (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    phones VARCHAR(500)
);

INSERT INTO 
    #contacts(first_name, last_name, phones)
VALUES
    ('John','Doe','(408)-123-3456,(408)-123-3457'),
    ('Jane','Doe','(408)-987-4321,(408)-987-4322,(408)-987-4323');


    SELECT id,
    first_name, 
    last_name,
    value phone
FROM 
    #contacts
    CROSS APPLY dbo.Split_fun(phones, ',');
```

Comment: WOW! this looks to be totally what i expect, any comments on efficiency of CROSS APPLY, i am browsing this though.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query for detail understanding.

```
USE [Your Database]
--create a table 'xc' to insert the data--
CREATE TABLE xc
(
Id INT,
[value] VARCHAR(100)
)
--Insert the data into table xc--
INSERT INTO dbo.xc
VALUES (1,'a,b,c,d')
(2,'b,e'),(3,'c'),(4,'r')

--Now run Update statement to get records a '.'(dot) delimited
UPDATE dbo.xc SET [value]=Replace([value],',','.')
--Now See the data---
Select * from dbo.xc
```

Please check snapshot as well.

[image]